# Java Multiple String Return

Tags: java

I'm trying to solve an exercise for a course I'm taking. I need to create a function that creates an array of inputs and returns the min and max values. Here's my simple code (pretty basic):

```
static String createVect()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Number of elements: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();

    int vector[] = new int[n];      

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Valor " + (i+1) + ": ");
        vector[i] = input.nextInt();
    }               

    int min = Arrays.stream(vector).min().getAsInt();
    int max = Arrays.stream(vector).max().getAsInt();       

    System.out.println("Min: " + min);
    System.out.println("Max: " + max);

    return Arrays.toString(vector); 

}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(createVect());   
}
```

It's working "ok", but I'd like to replace the System.out.print with returns but I'm not sure if I should encapsulate them or create other functions for the min and max. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can only have one `return` per method, so to return multiple `String`'s you'd have to put them in a data structure and then return the data structure

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in the [`summaryStatistics()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#summaryStatistics--) method. Your method could return an instance of [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) to carry the minimum and maximum (and other information). At the very least, you can use the method to avoid making multiple passes over the array:

```
IntSummaryStatistics stats = IntStream.of(vector).summaryStatistics();
System.out.printf("Min: %d%n", stats.getMinimum());
System.out.printf("Max: %d%n", stats.getMaximum());
```

For private implementation, using an array this way is quick and easy. But for a public API, it's inconvenient and error prone for clients, and can introduce to maintenance pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

Leverage arrays to return multiple values in a single data structure:

```
static int[] createVect()
{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.print("Number of elements: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();

    int vector[] = new int[n];      

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        System.out.print("Valor " + (i+1) + ": ");
        vector[i] = input.nextInt();
    }               

    int min = Arrays.stream(vector).min().getAsInt();
    int max = Arrays.stream(vector).max().getAsInt();       

    int[] returnArray; // declare returnArray as an array of integers
    returnArray = new int[2]; // create an array of 2 integers in returnArray
    returnArray[0] = min; // set the first element of returnArray to your min value
    returnArray[1] = max; // set the second element of returnArray to your max value

    return(returnArray); // return returnArray to the calling function
}
```

Further reading: [Returning an array as return value in a method - Emory MathCS](http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/170/Syllabus/09/array-return.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can't return different types of data in same time, you can use simply more
methods which will make it easier, and by creating the vector array as instance variable.

```
private static int vector[]; 
public static int getMax(int [] nums){
    return Arrays.stream(nums).max().getAsInt();
}
public static int getMin(int [] nums){
    return Arrays.stream(nums).min().getAsInt();
}

public static String createVect(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Number of elements: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();
    vector = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {        
        System.out.print("Valor " + (i+1) + ": ");
        vector[i] = input.nextInt();
    }               
    return Arrays.toString(vector); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {   
    System.out.println(createVect());  
    System.out.println("The min value: " + getMin(vector)); 
    System.out.println("The max value: " + getMax(vector));
}
```